# I can't get the id of the selected item via checkbox with IE

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble retrieving the id of the selected objects via checkbox.

I have not put all the code because it is too long, I have only entered what is needed.

```js
allart.Items.forEach(function (item) {               
                    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                    child.innerHTML =
                        '<td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.title + '</td><td>' + item.date + '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-item-id=+item.id+></td>';
                    table.appendChild(child);
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Selection</th>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br><br>

        <input type="button" value="GetID" onclick="getId" />
```

```js
function getId() {
            var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
            console.log(cbs.length);
            const ids = Array.from(cbs).map(function (cb) { cb.getAttribute("data-item-id") });
            console.log(ids);
            for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                deleteRow(ids[i]);
            }
        }
```

I can't get the ids variable.

**ids return length 1 but `data-item-id` is undefined.**

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  Does  `cb.getAttribute("data-item-id")` actually work on your array created from cbs?

Comment: @elunomas data-item-id is undefined

Comment: Why did you create **three** snippets instead of one?

Comment: @connexo To better clarify the code

Comment: That doesn't help your cause then, it damages it. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @connexo Maybe I wasn't clear about it. The problem is that the data-item-id is not read. Surely it must be a problem of bad syntax

Comment: You have a typo in your code. `...data-item-id=+item.id+></td>'` should be `...data-item-id="'+item.id+'"></td>'`. Also, inserting several rows, you end up with several elements with the same `id="myCheck"` which is not a valid HTML, so expect problems with that.

Comment: @elunomas I try but it doesn't work. Can you put that precisely as an answer?

Comment: (Sorry, I had a typo -- @Kosh had their comment correctly formatted!)  
`<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-item-id=+item.id+></td>` is a problem; it should be: ...`data-item-id="'+item.id+'">`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your const ids declaration to the following:

```
            ids = []
            cbs.forEach((checkedBox) => {
                ids.push(checkedBox.getAttribute("data-item-id"))
            })
```

(Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3madc64u/1/)

Comment: (...and I want to reemphasize @Kosh's comment above.)

Comment: always returns 1, does not return the element id. If you try to put 12 instead of 1 in your example, always return 1

Comment: even as @Kosh does I get nothing

Comment: @a_l_a_n_o I didn't realize the fiddle link changed after I edited it....sorry.  Does this one work for you?